# How to prevent files in a Maven Java import from specific package

Tags: java, maven, import, package

I have a Maven Java project with two pacakages inside src/main/java

com.myproject.maincode
com.myproject.resusablecode

Is there any way either through Java or with a Maven plugin/step to prevent the files inside the "com.myproject.resusablecode" package from importing files inside the package "com.myproject.maincode"?

Answer (score 3):

The proper way would be to separate the reusable code into its own project (or module) and add it as a dependency to your main code. It sounds like they have no reason to be in the same project (judging by the name).